# specify textbox value vba

Tags: vba

I have a textbox in a userform that help the user to add date to my databse, the user must enter a code in this format: "2019-254" ("a year - 3 Numbers"). If teh format is not correct an error msg appears to tell the user to repeat the operation using the correct format.
I know how to do this when working with dates like the foloowing code:

```
Private Sub Valider_Click()
If Not IsDate(TextBox_Date) Then
    MsgBox "Please enter a correct date:10/09/2019", vbCritical
Else
ws.Cells(24, Fin_Col_IT + 1) = CDate(Date_IT)
end if 
end sub
```

is it possibile to make a condition when not working with dates ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to check if the data entered follows a pattern, you can use the [like](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator) operator

```
If Not s Like "####-###" Then 
    MsgBox ...
End If
```

(`s` is the string you are checking)

If you also want to check if year is valid (let's say between 2000 and the current year) or the number has a specific value (eg <= 500) , you have to do the work manually using string functions. The following function can give you an idea how this could work:

```
Function checkInput(s As String) As Boolean
    checkInput = False
    If Not s Like "####-###" Then Exit Function              ' wrong pattern
    
    Dim tokens() As String, yyyy As Long, nnn As Long
    tokens = Split(s, "-")
    
    yyyy = Val(tokens(0))
    nnn = Val(tokens(1))
    
    If yyyy < 2000 Or yyyy > year(Now) Then Exit Function   ' wrong year
    If nnn > 500 Then Exit Function                         ' wrong number
    
    checkInput = True    ' Okay
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you, it works as I wanted. Quick and simple :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the next function, please. Do you also need to check if the first four digits are a year significance? If yes, the function must be adapted, but you must explain the logic for the valid range...

```
Private Function Valider_Nubmers(strNumb As String) As Boolean
  If strNumb Like "####-###" Then Valider_Nubmers = True
End Function
```

It can be called in this way:

```
Sub testValider_Nubmers()
  Dim x As String
  x = "2019-254"
  'x = "234-000"
  If Valider_Nubmers(x) Then
    MsgBox "Correct"
  Else
    MsgBox "Incorrect"
  End If
End Sub
```